# Too much information, PHP error?

Tags: php, mysql, security, sensitive-data

I'm making a custom wrapper for the `mysql_` functions when MySQLi, e.g. isn't available, and when it can't connect, it throws an exception. However, the fatal error output is this:

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Failed to
>   connect to database.' in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\MiniTicket\database.php`:16
> Stack trace:
> #0
>   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\MiniTicket\database.php`(49):
>   `MySQL->__construct('localhost', 'miniticket', 'mtu:r!Nj@~qR6f9...')`
> #1
>   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\MiniTicket\index.php`(3):
>   `require_once('C:\Program File...')`
> #2 {main} thrown in **C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\MiniTicket\database.php** on line **16**

As you can see, my database password is clearly displayed for everyone to see. Not good. I don't want to turn these messages off, especially in development, but I don't want sensitive information displayed either. Using `set_error_handler` is also not a great solution, because I have to parse everything, and that's prone to error.

So... is there an easy way to disable the display of the *parameters* in a function inside an error message, preferably through PHP and not in some configuration file?

Edit: Disabling the filepath except for the filename would be a bonus, too.

Comment: Is catching the Exception (and producing your own error message when you get 'Failed to connect to database') a possibility?

Comment: @nickb: I'd prefer not to do that, since this class will be everywhere and the exception may be handled in different ways. I suppose I could just `die` instead, but it doesn't feel quite as clean, especially if there can be error recovery.

Comment: You could always catch the Exception and throw your own Exception that contains just the `Exception::getMessage` from the original Exception, which wouldn't have the password in its stack trace.

Comment: If the host has neither mysqli nor PDO, it's time to switch hosts.

Comment: @outis: It's nothing to do with the host. I'm making open-source software, and I need a swap-in `database.php` for various RDBMS systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should separate your error handling between production and development where development displays the error information and production shows a friendly error message but does not output anything PHP does. Log the output to file instead.

Comment: Okay, I'll give that a try. Is there an easy way to divert the messages?

Comment: @minitech: You can turn all errors into exceptions (this makes warnings crash by default) and then use a custom exception handler to log them to a file. You could also use PHP's `error_log`.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your php.ini and set

```
display_errors = 0
```

If you don't have access to php.ini then at the top of your script(s) you need to add:

```
ini_set("display_errors", "0");
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

**This will stop *all errors* from being outputted to the browser**, and should probably only be done on your production system. Make sure you are still logging errors (via php.ini setting).

I'm not sure why this isn't the default configuration so that this situation doesn't happen in production environments.

Don't treat this as a solution to your software problem though, this is just meant to stop sensitive data from being displayed to the public.

*Note that you may need to restart Apache for the php.ini changes to take effect.*

Comment: -1 From the OP: **I don't want to turn these messages off**

Comment: @nickb Please re-read and update your comment. I added a note about this *only* being done on the production environment. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this is development though... this is an okay solution, but I'd prefer to hide the messages on development regardless.

Comment: @minitech FYI, I typically develop with display_errors off and `tail` the log file as I work. You're obviously in a windows environment so I don't know if this is an alternative for you or not. Google "linux tail for windows" if you want to try this out.